# Navigation Tabs in ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I have a small Android App which consists of 12 activities. I have also used SherlockActionBar for all the activites.

I want to add Navigation Tabs in action bar of one of my activity. I have done some googling but got to know that Navigation Tabs in ActionBar are used with Fragments.

So, my question is, how can I add Navigation Tabs to Action Bar without going for Fragments. I am not familiar with fragments and so don't want to use that.

Pease help me out here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: as far as I know  you can't have ActionBar Tabs without Fragments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StackOverflow is a better resource than google search for android (just my opinion). Perhaps this solution will meet your needs:

[Is it possible to display tabs without using fragments in android 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7499017/is-it-possible-to-display-tabs-without-using-fragments-in-android-3-0)